# How to use the PyNaCl secret key generated as environnement variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, pynacl

I am generating secret key using PyNaCl:

```
nacl.utils.random(nacl.secret.SecretBox.KEY_SIZE)
```

The keys look like:

```
b'\xa5\x8bL\xc4\xc0\xe6\xe3\xe5#\xb4{)\xd7uO(\xb11\x85\x88N\xfd\xf6>\nC\xb5\x95\\\xf1\x8b\xe8'
```

They are 32 bytes long and must stay 32 bytes long, how can I use them as environment variable?

**EDIT:**

I have try the following:

```
my_key = SecureMessage.generate #  b'\xe1\xd1\xef\x8anx\xb5\xf1n\xa8N/w\x90\xaejG\xdaN\x97\xbc\xb2\x90&\xedB\xa9\xf3/8\xa4?'
my_key_as_hex = my_key.hex() # e1d1ef8a6e78b5f16ea84e2f7790ae6a47da4e97bcb29026ed42a9f32f38a43f
my_key = bytes(my_key_as_hex, "utf-8") # b'e1d1ef8a6e78b5f16ea84e2f7790ae6a47da4e97bcb29026ed42a9f32f38a43f'
```

Comment: Convert them to something that can be stored as an environment variable, such as hexadecimal or uucode.

Comment: I test what you say didn't seem to work, I edit my post

Comment: @mel In what way didn't it work? That was perfectly good advice. Now all you need to do is just add it.

Comment: @Coldspeed There is a transformation between my original bytes and my final bytes look at the edit part

Comment: @mel Why do you want to convert it into bytes?

Comment: @Coldspeed I have a bytes I want to convert it in hex and then in a bytes again and it must be the same bytes as the beginning

Comment: Do `repr(my_key)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to go about it.

Generate your Key

```
key = nacl.utils.random(nacl.secret.SecretBox.KEY_SIZE)
```

At this point the `key` is in bytes format:

```
b"T\x93\xacsg'\xb4\x93\xc2+.\x8a\xe0\x8f\xd7\x8eCi\xd0\xd7\xb0\xa1\xdeX\x93\x05\xa2\xb6\xf6\x82`%"
```

As adviced in the comments, convert it to hexadecimal

```
hexed_key = key.hex()
```

That should give you something like:

```
5493ac736727b493c22b2e8ae08fd78e4369d0d7b0a1de589305a2b6f6826025
```

Store the above value in your environment variables. When it comes to time to use your secret key, just convert it back.

```
hexed_key = os.environ.get('HEXED_KEY', '')
box = nacl.secret.SecretBox(bytes.fromhex(hexed_key))
```

The part to note in the last line is `bytes.fromhex(hexed_key)` which will convert your hexadecimal into bytes

Your box is now ready to use...